# Case in Where Clause using datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I use a view to generate affected rows. A table `t1` has five columns with Mo, Tu, We, Th and Fr. Each columns has 0 if this day is not relevant or 1 if this day is relevant (e.g. 1,0,1,0,1 - Mo, We and Fr are relevant, Tu, Th are not relevant). Now I define the day actual date + 1 and will receive all rows which have a 1 in the affected column.

```
...
WHERE
CASE SUBSTRING(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1), 1, 2)
WHEN 'Mo' THEN t1.Mo = 1
WHEN 'Tu' THEN t1.Tu = 1
...
```

but this doesn't work. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You can't assign a value to a column in a `CASE` statement which is placed in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEPART` return a number, in case of `WEEKDAY` ranging (by default) from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)

```
WHERE
-- choose the relevant column
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1)
  WHEN 2 THEN t1.Mo
  WHEN 3 THEN t1.Tu
  WHEN 4 THEN t1.We
  WHEN 5 THEN t1.Th
  WHEN 6 THEN t1.Fr
-- compare with the expected value
END = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the value the `case` returns with the comparison, which is a different thing:

```
WHERE
1 = CASE SUBSTRING(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1), 1, 2)
         WHEN 'Mo' THEN t1.Mo
         WHEN 'Tu' THEN t1.Tu
         -- ...
    END
```

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1), 1, 2)` cannot work. WEEKDAY returns INT...

Answer (score 1):

DATEPART with WEEKDAY comes back with an INT value stating the day's index within a week.

Be carefull: This is depending on the system's culture! Have a look on @@DATEFIRST

Don't know what exactly you want to achieve but your code cannot work. There's no SUBSTRING with INT...

maybe something like this? This query will only return something on a day with index 1 or 2...

```
WHERE
1=CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1)
WHEN 1 THEN 1
WHEN 2 THEN 1
WHEN 3 THEN 2
END
```

Comment: Sorry - it was my fault - then statement is
    SUBSTRING(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1), 1, 2)

Comment: @Chris, OK, with DATENAME you can go like this, but I would NOT. This is heavily depending on your system's culture. Better use the INT function DATEPART and use @@DATEFIRST to get a system independent solution. Do you need any more help, or did the existing answers solve your problem?

Comment: @Chris, glad to read, that you solved your problem. Just for your information as you are new on SO: Everybody here giving answers is hungry for reputation points. We get them on upvotes to our answers or on accepts. You have accepted on already, well done! But please - whenever you ask something here - go through the answers and vote the helpful ones up. Your "thanks to all" as comment below a distinct answer won't reach the others...

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), using WEEKDAY with DATEPART is going to return an integer, not a string. You'll need to check for those integer values instead of calling substring and checking for things like 'Mo', 'Tu'

Here's a brief example. Also note that depending on settings (again, take a look at the MSDN article) the first day of the week could be different. Below I'm assuming that day 1 is Sunday.

```
SELECT CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() + 1) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday' 
    ELSE 'Other days' END
```